# Form Post with multiple values not working in php. Doesnt read the values correctly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I got a form post like this 
stepDatabase=users&stepFields=value1,value2,value3&stepDetails=value1,value2,value3

My php script looks like this and is not able to read the values correctly, except the stepDatabase value. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $stepDatabase = $_POST["stepDatabase"]; 
    $stepFields = $_POST["stepFields"]; 
    $stepDetails = $_POST["stepDetails"]; 

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$stepDatabase." (".$stepFields.") VALUES('".stepDetails."')");
```